# How do I style <a> which is retrieved from database?

Tags: html, css, asp-classic, external

I couldn't figure out how do I style a link which is pulled out from database. It might be simple but I have been struggling in it. I will be thankful if someone points out my mistake as I am not expecting coding help. I am attaching my snippet so that other can see what I am trying to do.

```css
tda2a a{font-size: 5px !important; color:red !important;}
```

```vb
Response.Write "<tr>" & _
    "<td id=""hometda2"" align=""right"" style=""width:75px;padding:15px 0"">" & _
    "<a id=""tda2a"" href=""http://www.example.com/" & RS("pal") & "-" & RS("productID") & """></a>" & _
    "</td>" & _
    "<td>" & RS("qty") & " - <a href=""http://""www.example.com/""" & RS("pal") & "-" & RS("productID") & """>" & RS("name")
IF RS("taste") <> "" THEN
    Response.Write " " & RS("taste")
END IF
Response.Write " by " & RS("brand") &"</a><br/>"
```

Comment: Can't you put a common class for all anchor tags which are pulled from DB?\

Comment: Did you forgot to put # on the CSS?

Comment: @VibhorDube: Thanks for responsing Vibhor, I could but its the only link so I thought of using id. Main issue is, its not identifying the id = tda2a I had given to anchor link. I tried keeping the id into different place as I am new in classic asp and its really really hard to get tutorials or any information for classic asp in website.

Comment: @marcelo2605: oops I forgot to keep # above . I apologize. but ya i had kept # in my css. Thanks Marcelo

Comment: Can you make the question more readable? Are you missing a </td> and a </tr>? Also <a/> is clearer here than <a></a>.

Comment: Molly, I've reformatted the code slightly so that it breaks across lines. The ` _` is a continuation marker, allowing you to break your current line across several (you must include a space before the `_`). *(So long as the peer review is favourable!)*

Answer (score 0):

In the above snippet pasted by you id is :
id=""hometda2""

This should be instead

> id="hometda2"

And your css rule currently is :
tda2a a{font-size: 5px !important; color:red !important;}

This should be instead

> #tda2a a{font-size: 5px !important; color:red !important;}

Comment: Hi Ya I kept # in css. And for id="hometda2" I kept double quote as it is insdide response.write.

Comment: As Molly noted, the doubled quotes around the id are correct: it's how you write out a double quote in VBScript. Also, `#tda2a a {...}` is looking for a parent element with id = "tda2a" which *contains* a link. It will not target a *link* which itself has that id, unless you have nested links (which aren't allowed in html).

Answer (score 0):

In your css,

```
tda2a a
```

is looking for the following html:

```
<tda2a><a href="...">...</a></tda2a>
```

Clearly, that isn't what your html contains. :)

If you want to target all links that are in the td with id=hometda2, you'd write

```css
#hometda2 a {...}
```

If you want to specifically target the link with id=tda2a, you'd write

```css
a#tda2a {...}
```

If you're actually writing out a bunch of links, consider using a class name instead of an id (since the latter must be unique), and use the exact same class name for all of the links.

```vbscript
Do Until RS.EOF
    Response.Write "<tr><td class='tinylink'><a href='www.example.com/"
    Response.Write RS("pal") & "-" & RS("productID")
    Response.Write "'>" & RS("name") & "</a></td></tr>"
    RS.Movenext
Loop
```

```css
td.tinylink {width:75px;padding:15px 0;text-align:right;}
td.tinylink a {font-size:5px !important; color:red !important;}
```

Comment: I tried the last option for bunch of links. But Its still not working, is it because I am trying in my android phone? Actually i am doing this for mobile website..

Comment: @Molly: there could be a cascade problem - does a parent element have a class or id with styling attached? It's also remotely possible that the Android browser is saying "5px is way too small for a phone, lemme increase that", except the `!important` directive *ought* to prevent that sort of "I'm-smarter-than-you" behavior.

Comment: yes, the parent element has id and has styling too..!important is really confusing. parent element is: .hometd2{width: 100% !important; padding: 0px !important;}. actually its a nested table so its too confusing. i really appreciate you trying to help me out

Comment: @Molly: it's possible, in fact recommended, to write entire websites without ever once using `!important`. But I digress. :) Try doing something like `#parentid td.tinylink a {...}`, or if that still doesn't help, `parentelement#parentid td.tinylink a {...}`.

Comment: @Molly: also, try cleaning up your code formatting - use consistent indenting, that sort of thing. It's possible that your html is invalid in some subtle way, and that's why the mobile browser is getting confused. (Also, I find that doubled double quotes are rarely worth the trouble: just use single quotes inside quoted strings. In most cases, they work just as well, and they make your code *much* less confusing.)

Comment: If I don't use !important, then how do I override the inline css (which is real trouble to mobile css) created initially for desktop version. Is it done by jquery? I know some people discouraging using !important :(

Comment: @Molly, do you not have control over the code, i.e. can't you remove the inline css?

Comment: No I don't. If I could remove them, then I could create two css page.I could transfer current inline css to desktop version css and another css for mobile then I don't need !important at all right? @Martha